# How do we know that the concept of mass is fundamental to physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

Since classical physics breaks down at a small scale, is it possible that mass itself is not a fundamental concept? Unless I am mistaken, HUP asserts that the fundamental behavior of all matter changes at a certain mass. Would it not make more sense that mass is just a useful concept to describe the motion of large objects, but is not itself a fundamental concept in physics? For very small objects, isn’t mass just a way of describing the degree to which the aggregate intermolecular forces of an object compare to the unknown force(s) that is/are truly responsible for the wave-like behaviour of small matter?

Comment: Hi Richard Houghton. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Ah OK, will do.  I was just worried nobody would see the edited version of the question after I updated it because it was marked as a duplicate.